# Switch on Type with Dictionary on Func and async / await

Tags: c#, dictionary, lambda, async-await

I'm trying to write this piece of code that doesn't compile (stuff deleted/simplifiied):

```
private async Task<PatientChartData> GetDomainListingSummaryMeta<T>(string phn) 
    where T : PatientChartBase, new()
{
    var getListingSummaryTypeSwitch = new Dictionary<Type, Func<????>> {
        { typeof(Documents), async () => await this.GetDocuments(phn) },
        { typeof(Encounters), async () => await this.GetEncounters(phn) },
        { typeof(Labs), async () => await this.GetLabs(phn) },
    };
    Task t = new Task(async () =>
    {
        // this is what code would look like without a switch, e.g.
        // await this.GetDocuments(phn);

        // but with a type switch, I want to do something like this:
        await getListingSummaryTypeSwitch(typeof(T))();
    });
    t.Start(); // notice, we are not waiting for this task to complete
}
```

GetDocuments returns Task, GetEncounters returns Task, etc. However, in my current design, I actually don't care about the response as I call them in a background thread that will have side-effects (e.g. putting them in database/cache, etc.) Please ignore the design issues with this being background threads.

My question is really about the syntax on how I make this work.

Comment: it doesn't compile...  you put that in your question but don't tell us what the error is....

Comment: Did you consider using polymorphism to solve this problem? Consider if all your types derive from a common type, they could all implement an abstract method of the base class or of a shared interface differently. Then you could just call this method and achieve type specific behaviour. Your dictionary would become obsolete.

Comment: please see the ??? in Func<> Plus, I'm not even sure if this will run properly and/or expected, even if it does compile. Should I use Action instead of Func? is the usage of async/await correctly used?

Comment: Would `Func<string, Task>` work for you?

Comment: And instead of using async lambda's with await, just pass the method (as they presumably already return Tasks).

Comment: Why are you creating a generic method here at all, when you know there's going to be a limited set of types you legally can handle? Why not just create N overloads with appropriate names, having the appropriate code? You should strive for "discoverability", the ability of the programmer (which may be you) to discover what the legal types and methods will be. With a generic method taking `T`, you're essentially saying "This method can take any type", and then afterwards it's all "nuh-uh fooled ya'".

Comment: I have a lot of doubts about this code. The intent of using all those asyncs/awaits is not clear and hence, future reader (which can be also you after one year) will not know if it is too wise or simply over-complicated.

Comment: Additionally, this is a fire-and-forget method, which is incorrectly defined as an `async` method, this will bring problems to the table, not solutions. When is the method (and its subtasks) done with what it does? How can you safely progress knowing that the data it is supposed to "Get" is safely "Gotten"?

Comment: All the comments are valid. It is prototype code at the moment, but still thought it was a valid syntactical question, some of it will disappear with proper redesign (e.g. polymorphism, etc.)

Comment: @lassevkarlsen is right. If your generic code only handles specific types correctly, it shouldn't be generic.

Comment: I agree... maybe generic is not correct... would it make any difference in my code question if my method passed in string domainName and switch on that? I was just opting to use the dictionary, which is the focus of the question with async methods.

Comment: How is the return value of the `Func` used? How do you get the return value of the whole function? Why are you wrapping `async` functions in another `Task`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing.
As many have pointed out - this code, while it works, is horrible design. This was just something quick-and-dirty that we were prototyping. It started with my boss asking for 1 domain... then he asked for 2 more, etc. I didn't want to refactor all my classes to use appropriate interfaces/polymorphism, as we were constantly changing things in the backend implementations, and (b) I figured this 'generic' use would be a quick way for me to prevent duplicate code. Hope this helps anyone out there that may need it.

```
            var actionSwitch = new Dictionary<Type, Action> {
                { typeof(Documents), async () => await _patientProcessorService.GetDocuments(phn) },
                { typeof(Encounters), async () => await _patientProcessorService.GetEncounters(phn) },
                { typeof(Labs), async () => await _patientProcessorService.GetLabs(phn) },
            };

            Task t = new Task(async () =>
            {
                actionSwitch[typeof(T)]();

            });
            t.Start();
```

Comment: There is no reason for any of those actions to be `async`, there is no reason to `await` the methods.  There is no reason to create a new task to invoke the action, and if there were, it shouldn't be an `async` lambda, nor should you be using the `Task` constructor to start tasks.

Answer (score 1):

you want to use the type as indexer not as argument?

```
        await getListingSummaryTypeSwitch[typeof(T)]();
```

Regarding your `Func<???>`: it must return an awaitable, otherwise you cannot use the `await` in front of your switch. Usually you would use `Func<Task>` or something generic like `Func<Task<resulttype>>`.

I won't discuss the other flaws (like wrapping in another Task) which are discussed in the comments-section of your question, because you said you simplified it.